# router5 programmaticaly navigation whith browser history

Tags: reactjs, browser-history

I'm using router5 in my react application. When i use a Link (router5 component) to navigate  from page to page,  that works correct. But when i use programmaticaly navigate to my route, the browser don't remember previuos state.

```js
import React, {useState} from "react";
import './StickerItem.css'


const StickerItem = ({id, name, props}) =>{
    let [select , setSelect] = useState(false);

    function toggleSelect() {
        props.stickerToggleSelectAC(id);
        select ? setSelect(false) : setSelect(true);
    }

    function routeSticker() {
        /* this code don't save transition from  route to route */
        props.router.navigate('stickers', {id: id}, {replace: true});
    }
    
    return <div onClick={toggleSelect}
                onDoubleClick={routeSticker}
                className={"link_sticker" + " " + (select? "active" : "")}
                key={id}> {name} </div>
    
    /* this code works correct and i can navigate from page /stickers/18 to /stickers/40 and forward  in my browser*/
    
    // return <Link    routeName="stickers"
    //                 routeParams={{id}}
    //                 activeClassName="active_link_sticker"
    //                 className={"link_sticker" + " " + (select? "active" : "")}
    //                 key={id}> {name} </Link>
};


export default  StickerItem;
```

Answer (score -1):

I just remove {replace: true} from
`props.router.navigate('stickers', {id: id}, {replace: true});`
and now it works for me. Sometimes we need just write our problems))